# Start vi at the last line

Tags: command-line, autocomplete, vi

I often find myself editing one of a set of configuration files by adding lines at the end. For editing I use `vi` (from `bash`) and currently use:

```
vi +$(wc -c /home/john/master/tried.cfg)
```

The above works, but it makes filename completion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> impossible, which is a nuisance when changing the filenames after scrolling back on the commandline.

Is there an easier way to do go to the last line of the opened file? Maybe with the `+{}` commandline option that `vi` offers. Or is there some way to make commandline completion in the `$()` work?

Comment: try `vi +$ filename`

Comment: I had to try out your command to see how it worked. DId not realise immediately that `wc -c` echoes the filename as well as the word count.

Comment: Pressing G after opening vi is another approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
vi +$ /home/john/master/tried.cfg
```

and do a way with the `$()` part completely. You don't have to escape the `$` as it is followed by a space and `bash` doesn't expand it.

You can also use this to go to, e.g. the one before last line:

```
vi +\$-1 /home/john/master/tried.cfg
```

but then you have to escape the `$` with a backslash.